# Convert simple INSERT to multi-table transaction inside Postres?

Tags: postgresql

I have an application that uses a library that sends simple INSERTs to Postgres.

Here is an illustrative example:

```
INSERT INTO COMPANIES (company_name)
VALUES ('Acme, Inc.');
```

However, I need to take this a bit further and embed the simple INSERT into a transaction that also inserts into other tables, like this:

```
BEGIN;

-- some insert to another table first

INSERT INTO COMPANIES (company_name)
VALUES ('Acme, Inc.');

-- some insert to yet another table last

COMMIT;
```

The simplest solution would be to modify the library's code to do what I need. However, I don't really want to do that as it makes patch management for the library very difficult.

An alternative would be to catch and modify the INSERT via the ORM just before it gets handed over to Postgres. However, this is also not a great approach as it requires dealing with undocumented internals of the ORM, which might change with new versions of the ORM.

I have therefore been looking for a way to do this inside Postgres.

My focus has been on a `TRIGGER` that would fire on `INSERT` to the relevant table, using the `INSTEAD OF` specifier.

And this is the point where I'm stuck, as this seems to only work for views.

Is what I'm trying to do feasible? Might somebody have a code example?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your example wouldn't compile... Learn to use appropriate quotes.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated. Apologies.

Comment: I'm missing something, why are you looking at INSTEAD OF when you want to keep the current insert on the current table, but you also want to do something else? A trigger can do that, no problem

Comment: I could use BEFORE and AFTER to accomplish what I need, but it wouldn't give me the safety of having all three INSERTS in one transaction block. But maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: All three INSERT would be in a single transaction (a transaction you execute INSERT INTO COMPANIES ).

Comment: Maybe I'm confused about how triggers work. I would like to ensure I have an all-or-nothing operation for all three INSERTS together. Let's say I run the simple INSERT in the first example, and have a BEFORE trigger and an AFTER trigger to handle the other two INSERTs I mentioned, but the server fails after the BEFORE trigger completes, would I not end up with only one INSERT (rather than three)?

Comment: @why_is_this you will have all or nothing if you simply put all inserts into transaction, no triggers needed

Comment: @dfens: Yes, that would be how I would do it if I could write the query the way I want it inside the application. However, as explained in the question, this is complicated for various reasons. I would thus prefer to have only the simple, single-table INSERT query arrive at Postgres and have Postgres somehow enrich this with two other INSERTS, but  inside some safety wrapper that ensures "all-or-nothing" for the three INSERTs together. The only safety wrapper I know would be a transaction block.

Comment: Ok. If this is your orm limitation maybe you could go with sth like `with insert_1 as (insert into...), insert_2 as (insert into...) select 1`

Comment: Thank you @dfens, "with" looks like an approach that would work.

Comment: @all: I think I misunderstood how triggers work from an all-or-nothing perspective. After researching some more and experimenting with failing AFTER triggers, it looks like there is one "big" transaction wrapper around the following: 1) BEFORE trigger statement, 2) the original statement that triggered the trigger(s),  and 3) the AFTER trigger statement.

Comment: I think the simple answer in my question is therefore to simply use regular BEFORE and AFTER triggers. Thank you all again for your help.